# Zoom map to include all marker points [YMKPoint], YandexMapsMobile Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, yandex-maps, yandex-api, yandex-mapkit

How can I zoom map to include all marker point into visible area?

I have an array of points, was trying to configure `BoundingBox()`, but have no idea how to set/find `southWest` and `northEast` values from `[YMKPoint]`.

```
.cameraPosition(with: .init(southWest: ?, northEast: ?))
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a ready code for you, but hope this will help.

As you have an array of all the `[YMKPoint]` from that array you need to filter all the points which belong to the **southWest** zone & **northEast** zone.

See below statement that will help you to filter the points:

***Latitude:**  Positive values indicate north latitude and negative values indicate south latitude.*

***Longitude:** Positive values indicate east longitude, and negative values indicate west longitude.*

After filtering the array based on two zones, you need to sort the array based on the points which is far for both the zones **southWest** & **northEast**.

Once array is sorted you will be able to create a `BoundingBox` by selecting first point from both the sorted array of zones.

[image: See this image to understand how the co-ordinates are placed on the map using a graph.]

See this image to understand how the co-ordinates are placed on the map using a graph.